# numpy.loadtxt Skipping multiple rows

Tags: python, numpy, syntax

I believe the title of this thread explains what I am looking for. I am curious to know what the syntax is for skipping multiple rows; I can't seem to find such information anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried to slice it?

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean.

Comment: you state that the title explains what you require but the comments in the answer below show that more information was needed (first n rows, named rows, equal intervals ... )

Comment: No, you see, I stated that I 'believe' the title was sufficient, but evidently it was not. I reckon that that could be attributed to the fact that I am wholly ignorant to python--in fact, ignorant to programming in general.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `help(np.loadtxt)`. You'll find the `skiprows` parameter will allow you to skip the first `N` rows:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: help(np.loadtxt)
Help on function loadtxt in module numpy.lib.npyio:

loadtxt(fname, dtype=<type 'float'>, comments='#', delimiter=None, converters=None, skiprows=0, usecols=None, unpack=False, ndmin=0)
    ...
    skiprows : int, optional
        Skip the first `skiprows` lines; default: 0.
```

Thus, to skip `N` rows, you'd say

```
np.loadtxt(fname, skiprows=N)
```

---

If you need to filter rows other than the *first* `N` rows, use `np.genfromtxt` which can take an iterator which yields strings as its first argument:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = (line for line in f if predicate(line))
    arr = np.genfromtxt(lines)
```

---

To skip a sequence of rows in the middle, such as rows 47--50, you could use `itertools` like this:

```
import itertools as IT

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = IT.chain(IT.islice(f, 46), IT.islice(f, 4, None))
    arr = np.genfromtxt(lines)
```

Comment: But how does it know of which N rows to skip?

Comment: So, using np.genfromtxt, if I wanted to skip the rows 47,48,49, and 50, I would type lines(47,48,49,50) in the argument?

Comment: No, as is stated in `help(np.loadtxt)`, `skiprows` is only useful for skipping the first `N` rows. To skip rows in the middle of the file, you'll need to form an iterator which yields only the lines you want. I've edited the post above to show one such way.

Answer (score 3):

If you already know the row numbers you wish to skip, then you can also use:

```
import numpy as np
InputFile = './Filename.txt'
Dataset = np.loadtxt(InputFile, skiprows= 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5)
print(Dataset)
```

This will skip the first five rows and print the remaining data.