# How to read a matrix from a textfile

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to read a textfile with matrix and put it in a list,

but I am using two loops here and i want my function to be faster,

So is there a better way than my code?

```
def read_file(path_to_file):
    mylist=[]
    for eachLine in open(path_to_file,'rt'):
        mylist.append([int(eachRow) for eachRow in eachLine.split()])
    return mylist
```

Updated Code with numpy

```
def read_file(path_to_file):
file = path_to_file
list = np.loadtxt(file, skiprows=0)
print(list)
```

i got an error `ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 2`

Example txtfile(the first line indicating how many rows or columns always symmetric )

```
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Comment: This question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com, since you're facing no problems

Comment: Is numpy available to you? [`numpy.loadtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

Comment: Yes, but i couldn't make it with numpy,

Comment: Can you show me how please

Comment: Try to post an example of your data and why `numpy` is not working for you

Comment: i edited my post with the code of numpy i tried

Comment: Your example implies that the file is space-delimited lines of text. `mylist = numpy.loadtxt(path_to_file)`. Whether numpy is a good choice depends on what you do with it afterwards. More generally, that code is already fast... likely faster than reading the file unless its already in your system RAM cache. Its not something I would normally try to speed up.

Comment: Your first line is different than the other lines. try use the `skiprows` argument. `skiprows : int, optional, Skip the first skiprows lines; default: 0.`

Comment: thanks but i want learn how to put a matrix from file to list using numpy for future if i needed it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy.loadtxt Skipping multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301967/numpy-loadtxt-skipping-multiple-rows)

Comment: i tried to skip it but still the same error i am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can get much faster for reading the file. Yes, you have a nested for loop, and thus quadratic complexity, but that's for reading a *quadratic* matrix, so this seems fine. You could, however, use `with` to ensure that the file is closed properly, and remember to skip the first row:

```
def read1():
    with open("data.txt") as f:
        next(f)
        return [[int(x) for x in row.split()] for row in f]
```

You *could* use `numpy.loadtxt` with `skiprows=1` ...

```
import numpy as np
def read2():
    return np.loadtxt("data.txt", skiprows=1)
```

... but this seems to be in fact five times *slower* than the nested list comprehension, at least for this tiny 3x3 matrix.

```
In [10]: %timeit test.read1()
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.1 us per loop
In [11]: %timeit test.read2()
1000 loops, best of 3: 245 us per loop
```

Comment: Addendum: For larger matrices, the "overhead" by numpy is less dramatic. For a 100x100 matrix of integers, `numpy` takes just slightly longer -- but longer, still.

Comment: In my experience, `numpy.loadtxt` always takes longer than a minimal manual `open` and an iteration, because `loadtxt` is doing exactly that with same additional bells and whistles, which you don't always need. If reading/access time is an issue, it might be beneficial to save the data in binary format and use [`numpy.memmap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) or [`numpy.fromfile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html). I prefer the former, but make sure to use `mode=c` or `mode=r`.